# match string with following element sibling

Tags: xml, string, xslt, match, xslt-2.0

I have a paragraph that looks like this.

```
<paragraph>The quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog (<xref refId="ID2-1">2</xref>).</paragraph>
```

I would like to use XSLT to enclose the () in a superscript.

```
<p>The quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog <sup>(<a rid="ID2-1">2</a>)</sup>.</p>
```

I could not achieve this using the standard matches and following-sibling::*[1][self::xref] functions.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Please note that the paragraph may also have multiple xrefs or group of xrefs

Comment: Which version of XSLT does your processor support?

Comment: Im using xslt 2.0

Answer (score 2):

It should be doable with three patterns matching on the `xref` and the preceding and following sibling `text()` nodes (which need to be manipulated as well to strip the parenthesis):

```
  <xsl:template match="xref[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()][ends-with(., '(')]][following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()][starts-with(., ')')]]">
      <sup>
          <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
          <xsl:next-match/>
          <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
      </sup>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="text()[ends-with(., '(')][following-sibling::node()[1][self::xref[following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()][starts-with(., ')')]]]]">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, string-length(.) - 1)"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="text()[starts-with(., ')')][preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::xref[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()][ends-with(., '(')]]]]">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzkTcA is XSLT 3 but instead of declaring the identity transformation with `xsl:mode` as the underlying base transformation you can of course for an XSLT 2 processor define a template doing that.